# what's the default dash demuxer for YouTube on Chrome (or other browser)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

Anyone knows **what is the default dash demuxer for YouTube on Chrome (or other browser)?**
It is, if you play MPEG DASH on YouTube of your browser (Chrome, Opera...), you will receive the demuxed A\V packets(MSE?) at your player's pipeline so you need NOT to do demux (but decode & render the received A\V packets directly). 
I am wondering **where it takes place**? as well as **which player takes this responsibility**? (I guess it is a kind of JavaScript player).

Thanks~

Comment: are you referring to videos in a `<video>` tag?

Comment: hi Jaromanda: yes, exactly I did.

Comment: then it's handled by the browser